# Selenium WebDriver: Clicking Elements and Dropdown Selections Timeout Issue

Tags: python, function, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm currently working on a web scraping project using Selenium WebDriver in Python. Initially, the code worked as expected, but as I introduced functions to simplify and modularize the code, I started encountering issues with elements timing out and becoming unclickable.

The specific problem arises when trying to click on elements using the click_element function and selecting dropdown options with the select_dropdown_option function. These functions use WebDriverWait for element visibility and clickability.

I've noticed that without the functions, the code works fine. However, once I introduce these functions to make the code more maintainable and readable, the elements are not being located within the specified timeout, leading to TimeoutException errors.

I've tried various solutions, including increasing timeouts, waiting for different conditions, and scrolling elements into view before clicking. Despite these attempts, the issue persists.

The website Im accesing to features a questionnaire designed to process various combinations of user responses. Upon completion, it computes a numerical value, which is the one Im trying to store in a Pandas DataFrame.

I would apreciate any help in understanding why introducing functions seems to impact the behavior of the Selenium WebDriver interactions. Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

The original code that works without any problems:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import pandas as pd


# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['var1', 'var2', 'budget'])

# Define lists for interactions
eligible = ['Yes', 'No']
level = ['Term1', 'Term2', 'Term3']

# Opciones de navegación
options =  webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\...\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://example.com')


#Login:-----------------------------------------------------------------------    
WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#username'))) \
    .send_keys('example@mail.com')
    
WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#password'))) \
    .send_keys('1234')    
    
WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
                                       'button.login_button_example'.replace(' ','.')))) \
    .click()

        
#Loop through the questions:--------------------------------------------------
for answ in eligible:    
    
    for term in level:    

        if answ == 'Yes':
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
                .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                   '/html/...yes../span[1]'))) \
                .click()        
        else: #No
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
                .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                   '/html/...no.../span[1]'))) \
                .click()                          
            
        # Find the input field associated with the dropdown.
        #Maintaining and cleaning the home – level of independence:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
            .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(((By.ID, 
                                             "select2-...-container"))))\
            .click()
        
        item_to_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                             f"//li[text()='{term}']")
        item_to_select.click()
        
        
        #Move to the calculation tab
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
            .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                               '/html/.../button[2]'))) \
            .click()
        
        #Click on "recalculate"    
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
            .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                               '/html/.../button'))) \
            .click()    
        
        
        # Wait for the element to be present in the DOM
        budget_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "budget"))
        )
        
        # Get the text content from the element
        budget_text = budget_element.text
        
        df = df.append({'var1': answ, 'var2': term, 'budget': budget_text}, ignore_index=True)
        
        #Move back to the form tab
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
            .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                               '/html/.../button[1]'))) \
            .click()
# Close the browser
driver.quit()

# Print the final DataFrame
print(df)
```

The modular version of the code that is showing the TimeoutException:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

#Function to log-in to my account.
def login(username, password):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#username'))).send_keys(username)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#password'))).send_keys(password)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.login_button_example'))).click()

#Function for clickable elements
def click_element(xpath):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()

#Function for selecting dropdown options
def select_dropdown_option(dropdown_id, term):
    click_element(f"//label[@for='{dropdown_id}']")
    item_to_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//li[text()='{term}']")
    item_to_select.click()

#Function to recalculate the budget for each iteration
def recalculate_budget():
    click_element("/html/.../button[2]")
    click_element("/html/.../button")

#Function to move back to the questionnaire
def move_to_form_tab():
    click_element("/html/.../button[1]")

#Navigation options
options =  webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\...\\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)

# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['var1', 'var2', 'budget'])

# Login to the website
login('example@gmail.com', '1234')


# Define lists for your interactions
eligible = ['Yes', 'No']
level = ['Term1', 'Term2', 'Term3']

for answ in eligible:
    for term in level:
        if answ == 'Yes':
            click_element('/html/.../span[1]') #xPath to "yes" button
        else:
            click_element('/html/.../span[1]') #xPath to "no" button

        select_dropdown_option("select2-...-container", term)
        recalculate_budget()

        # Wait for the element to be present in the DOM
        budget_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "budget"))
        )

        # Get the text content from the element
        budget_text = budget_element.text

        df = df.append({'var1': answ, 'var2': term, 'budget': budget_text}, ignore_index=True)
        move_to_form_tab()

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

# Print the final DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing "//label[@for='{dropdown_id}']" in the code the works.  Maybe that's the issue?  You should probably include the full exception in your post.  (It should cite the locator...)